# Angular/ ngrx store: argument of type 'mystate' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I have implemented state management using ngrx/store (Version 5.2.0) in  angular (Version 5.2.9) application and with a typescript version(2.5.3).

I was having issue when i try to select the store and subscribe to it.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"appStateData"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"appState"'.
```

app.module.ts

```js
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { appReducer } from "./store/app.reducers";
...
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({ appStateData: appReducer }),
  ],
```

reducer

```js
import * as AppActions from "./app.actions";

export interface AppState {
  appState: State;
}
export interface State {
  values: [
    {
      modalStatus: boolean;
      searchString: string;
      chemString: string;
    }
  ];
}
const intialState: State = {
  values: [
    {
      modalStatus: false,
      searchString: null,
      chemString: null
    }
  ]
};

export function appReducer(state = intialState, action) {
 switch cases for all actions
 ...
}
```

my component and subscribe to store

```js
 import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
 import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
 
 import * as fromAppReducer from "../store/app.reducers";
 
 export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public store: Store<fromAppReducer.AppState>) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
  this.store.select('appStateData').subscribe(data => {
      this.searchString = data.values.slice(-1)[0].searchString;
    });
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from this:

```
export interface AppState {
  appState: State;
}
```

and this:

```
constructor(public store: Store<fromAppReducer.AppState>) {}
```

In your constructor, you're telling the component that the provisioned store has slices of state that align with the interface `AppState`.  The interface `AppState` has one member, also named `appState`.  The Typescript compiler is helping you by saying you can only select a slice of state that exists -- in this case, that's a string "type" called `appState`.

As a result, you need to change this:

```
this.store.select('appStateData')
```

to this:

```
this.store.select('appState')
```

Then subscribe and get the values out.

A better option in general would be to use selectors, which are detailed here:

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/selectors.md